# UITableView with Footerview ( emdedded text view) issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, ios8

I am building this simple example where there is a UITableView and a footerview associated with the uitableview. To avoid overlapping the keyboard I added the keyboard show an hide notifications and it works fine...  Initially when the app load the uitextview in the footerview is placed correctly at the bottom of the UITableView.. But once type in some text and dismiss the keyboard the footerview vanishes and goes far below the viewable region. Any idea why this would happen?

On application load

[image]

On editing

[image]

After the keyboard is dismissed

[image]

At this point the uitextfield vanishes and is hidden below the tab bar.  Here is the code for keyboard show and dismiss events.

```
func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    println("Keyboard will show notification")
    var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight:CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

    var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as CGFloat

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}

func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

}
```

Comment: Just from curiosity, did you check the table view insets before the keyboard is shown? Are the insets zero ?

Comment: can you set the view that contains the uitextview as a global variable in the class and check its coordinates before and after the display of the keyboard

Comment: @danypata: Yes I verified the table view insets before the keyboard is show its 0,0

Comment: @code the bounds and the tableview and the frame for the footerview is changing.. ![More info](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s209/sh/1f91e00c-bf53-4986-bed7-c8e2bd157d55/1325576c1030a7b0ca49e23ab18e362e) https://www.evernote.com/shard/s209/sh/1f91e00c-bf53-4986-bed7-c8e2bd157d55/1325576c1030a7b0ca49e23ab18e362e

Comment: Are you using auto-layout ?

Comment: Yes I am using autolayouts